# powershell data import performance

Tags: powershell

I have an issue with the powershell data import to SQL.
I perform the data import CSV files placed in a remote server to another DB server. There are around 2400 CSV files which vary in size from 1KB to 30 GB. I am reading the each file content and import the same to DB. But this take more than a day to complete around thousand files, so in order to complete all the 2400 files two or three will be taken. But this is not agreed for the business. I an using folowing command to import the files.

```
Get-ChildItem $CsvFilePath | Foreach-Object {
    $DataImport = Import-Csv $_.FullName | Out-DataTable
    Write-DataTable -ServerInstance $server -Database $Database -TableName $Table -Username $Username -Password $Password -Data $DataImport
}
```

How can i improve the performance so that i can complete the importing within short period of time preferably less than a day. Any one please help me by providing a practical solution for it.

Thanks
Jerin

Comment: Are all of these being uploaded to the same DB?

Answer (score 0):

If your server has more than 1 core, you should use `-AsJob` parameter or a `Start-Job` cmdlet to start a single-threaded import of one CSV at a time, and your master script should monitor the number of jobs running, making more jobs out of your CSV files list once there are less than "number of cores on the server -1" jobs running. The number of cores is best hardcoded, as you're apparently strict in timespan to develop the import script.

And it'll be better if you transfer all the CSVs to the local storage beforehand. If you can't, okay but the importing process might slow down because of the bandwidth and remote storage speed limitation placed over your server's existing limits.

[Some data about Powershell jobs to digest.](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_asjob.htm)

Comment: HI Vesper , can you please expalain little more about your first point. i can't follow you

Comment: You make an import a job, this means a separate `powershell.exe` process running a script vs one file, which exits after finishing import. By default Powershell uses one process (one operation at once), thus all import is sequential, I am advising you to use more than a single thread to work with more than a single file at a time. This lessens time spent on importing.

Comment: I got ur point like you are advising me  to use asyncronous call right?

Comment: Basically, yes. You make two scripts, one is called asynchronously, and processes **ONE** CSV which is passed to it as a parameter, then exits. The other (master) script maintains the whole list of CSVs to import, and launches one single-file import script per file if there are not more than X (defined by you) processes already running, and waits in sleep cycle while these work, adding more as needed, until the file list is fully processed.

Comment: Another thing: You have asked more than one question already, and you even comment that the solution provided in an answer worked for you. Please accept one answer per question that helped you the most, if there is any. This will give you some reputation and help StackOverflow as community.

Comment: I am trying with your asynchrounous option.,,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your size distribution is, but 1KB - 30GB is a pretty wide range.  Once you start getting over a few hundred MB, I'd suspect memory management may be adding a lot of process overhead and creating a performance drag.

You might consider switching to a process of doing a Get-Content with a -ReadCount that breaks them down into manageable chunks for import.